# JSP form: HttpStatus 400: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have this in a jsp:

```html
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="answer">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td><label for="chosenanswer">answer: </label> </td>
   <td>
    <form:radiobutton path="chosenAnswer" value="Male" />Male
    <form:radiobutton path="chosenAnswer" value="Female" />Female
    <form:radiobutton path="chosenAnswer" value="Other" />Other 
   </td>
     </tr>
```

When I hit the submit button, I get a HTTPStatus 400 with this message:

```
 The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

This is what I have in my Controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/take-exam-{examid}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String takeExam(@PathVariable String examid, ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("answer",new SelectedAnswer());
    model.addAttribute("questiontext","Dummy question text");
    return "exam";
}

/*
 *Answering a question
 */
@RequestMapping(value = { "/take-exam-{examid}" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String answerQuestion(SelectedAnswer answer, BindingResult result,
        ModelMap model, @PathVariable String ssn) {

    model.addAttribute("answer", "SelectedAnswer: "+answer.toString());
    model.addAttribute("success", "SelectedAnswer: "+answer.toString());
    return "success";
}
```

My SelectedAnswer class is:

```
public class SelectedAnswer {
    private String chosenAnswer;

    public String getChosenAnswer() {
        return chosenAnswer;
    }

    public void setChosenAnswer(String chosenAnswer) {
        this.chosenAnswer = chosenAnswer;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "SelectedAnswer = "+chosenAnswer;
    }
}
```

The page loads fine, but when I hit the submit button, I get the error with HttpStatus 400:  The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
Any idea what is going on?

Thanks,

Regards,
Serban

Comment: Why is there a `ssn` param in `answerQuestion` method? Trying changing that to `examid`

Comment: You just answered my question! That parameter was supposed to be named examid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is there a ssn param in answerQuestion method? Trying changing that to examid